# A peculiar integral using Leibnitz rule of integration?

Tags: integration, leibniz-integral-rule

[Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html#:%7E:text=The%20Leibniz%20integral%20rule%20gives,functions%20of%20the%20differential%20variable%2C&text=It%20is%20sometimes%20known%20as%20differentiation%20under%20the%20integral%20sign.&text=(Woods%201926).) while explaining (rather very briefly) the Leibnitz rule of integration, aka derivative under an integral sign, mentions that this method may be used to evaluate peculiar integrals such as $$\phi(\alpha)=\int_0^{\pi}\ln(1-2\alpha \cos x+\alpha^2)~\mathrm dx=2\pi \ln|\alpha| \\ \text{for}~~ |\alpha|>1$$

This seems a tricky (or peculiar one) indeed!

How would one go about proving it?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the [full text](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.$b529317) for the source that Wolfram Mathworld mentions. See page 144 of the text, or page 160 of the electronic document. It reads:

> The principle of differentiating under the integral sign may sometimes be used to evaluate a definite integral. For example, take
> $$\phi(\alpha) =\int_0^\pi \log(1-2\alpha\cos(x)+\alpha^2)\mathrm dx\tag{11}$$ $$ \frac{\mathrm d\phi}{\mathrm d\alpha}=\int_0^\pi \frac{-2\cos(x)+2\alpha}{1-2\alpha\cos(x)+\alpha^2}\mathrm dx \\ =\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^\pi \left[1-\frac{1-\alpha^2}{1-2\alpha\cos(x)+\alpha^2}\right]\mathrm dx \\ =\frac{\pi}{\alpha}-\frac{2}{\alpha}\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]\bigg|^{x=\pi}_{x=0}$$

> As $x$ varies for **(*from?*)** $0$ to $\pi$, $\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tan\frac{x}{2}$ varies through positive values for **(*from?*)** $0$ to $\infty$ when $-1<\alpha<1$, and $\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tan\frac{x}{2}$ varies through negative values from $0$ to $-\infty$ when $\alpha<-1$ or $\alpha>1$.
> Hence

> $$\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]\bigg|^{x=\pi}_{x=0}=\frac{\pi}{2}~~~\text{when}~~-1<\alpha<1 \\ \text{and}~~\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tan\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]\bigg|^{x=\pi}_{x=0}=-\frac{\pi}{2}~~~\text{when}~~\alpha<-1~\text{or}~\alpha>1$$
> Therefore
> $$\frac{\mathrm d\phi}{\mathrm d\alpha}=0~~\text{when}~~-1<\alpha<1, \\ \text{and}~~\frac{\mathrm d\phi}{\mathrm d\alpha}=\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}~~\text{when}~~\alpha<-1~\text{or}~\alpha>1;$$
> whence $\phi=C_1$ when $-1<\alpha<1$, and $\phi=\pi\log(\alpha^2)+C_2$ when $\alpha<-1$ or $\alpha>1$.

> We may determine $C_1$ by placing $\alpha=0$ in $(11)$. Then, $C_1=0$. Hence $$\phi=0~ \text{when}~ -1<\alpha<1\tag{12}$$ To determine $C_2$ in the same manner we should need to substitute in $(11)$ a value of $\alpha$ greater numerically than $1$. This is not convenient. Instead we will place $\alpha=\frac{1}{\beta}$, where $-1<\beta<1$. Then
> $$\phi(\alpha)=\int_0^\pi \big[\log(1-2\beta\cos x+\beta^2)-\log\beta^2\big]\mathrm dx \\ =-\log \beta^2~\int_0^\pi\mathrm dx~~~~~\text{[by (12)]} \\ =-\pi\log\beta^2 \\ =\pi \log\alpha^2~~~\text{when}~\alpha<-1~\text{or}~\alpha>1$$
> Therefore $C_2=0$. The definition of $\phi(\alpha)$ is now complete.

---

And it goes on. Note that by the properties of $\log$, $\pi\log(\alpha^2)=2\pi\log |\alpha|$, so there are no problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to this paper "arXiv 2308.09619v1 On the Leibnitz Rule for Differentiating Under the Integral Sign", which provides a very short solution using the complex representation of $\cos(x)$ (Example 2, page 3).